# How do I make the action of my form the src of my iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, iframe

```
<form id="submit" action="" method="post">
```

I need my form to submit data to the src of the iframe. This src is constantly changing depending on user action.

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="math_iframe.php" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
```

So I would like it to do something like

```
<form id="submit" action="<iframe src="math_iframe.php"" method="post">
```

Please note : I would like the stay on the current page.

Comment: JavaScript! When the enter button on the form is pressed, have it change the source. I suggest jQuery.

Comment: @PaulBGD Just tried that :\ While it did work, it sent me to the next page, I would like to remain where I am.

Comment: Remove the action/method.

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery:

```
$('#submit').on('submit',function(e){
    $(this).attr('action',$('#iframe').attr('src'));
});
```

DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/M6wHa/